# How to navigate to standard pages like SystemOverview, CompanyInformation using lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I trying to navigate to SystemOverview and CompanyInformation pages from the lightning components.

Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<a onclick="{!c.goToSystemOverviewPage}" style="width:100%;">   
    API Information
</a>
   <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToURL" type="EVENT" />
```

JS Controller

```
    goToSystemOverviewPage: function(component, event, helper) {

var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
urlEvent.setParams({
    "url": "https://samba--devat.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/SystemOverview/home"
});
urlEvent.fire();
}
```

But it's not working not sure what's missing here.

Answer (score 0):

The "navigateToURL" event is now being deprecated, so you need to do it by means of the new "lightning:navigation" standard component.

Please check the docs with intructions on how to implement the new navigation pattern for Lightning Components here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation

I hope this is helpful.
Thanks,
Julio

Comment: Yes, I have seen this summer'18 feature for navigation but I don't find anything in Pagereference Type which allow me to navigate on the standard page. Because for SystemOverview, CompanyProfile not metadata is expossed which I can use in the pagereference.

Comment: navigateToURL, navigateToSobjects etc not working for standard setUp pages, done the navigation using javascript. Issue resoved.